# How to get a specific part of string with specific condition?

Tags: java

I've following kind of string:

`http://www.example.org/ab/app/ram/ri/000000000000004`

I just want last part of the string i.e. `000000000000004` which changes every time. How can I get it using Java?

Comment: Did you just search anything before asking ? String manipulation in Java is over-documented on the internet.

Comment: please do some basic searching as this question seems to be easily achivable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int))

```
String result= yourUrl.substring(yourUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes and just use `\\d+` like  [here](http://regex101.com/r/wG6eJ0/1)

PS : *Suresh's* answer is better than mine :P

Comment: @Julien - I agree. Suresh had already posted that answer. I am just giving *another* approach.

Comment: And it's a good thing to show different approaches :) I posted my comment right before your edited your answer with "Suresh's answer is better than mine :P" ;) So we are on the same line ^^

Comment: I disagree, regexp for such task is overkill, the best approach should be enforced or we may end up with ppl building an URL, and then extracting parts from it, or looping on each char backward to find last '/'. They're all working solutions, but that won't imply they're good.

Answer (score 1):

ofcoure i have put the code in C#, should be slight change with syntax in java.i have posted it just to let the questioner know the direction.

```
string yourUrl = "http://www.example.org/ab/app/ram/ri/000000000000004";
string[] result = yourUrl.Split('/');
string finalRes = result[result.Length - 1];
```

Comment: It's nearly the same in Java except for the conventions : Only classes (and constants but as they are supposed to be written in full capital it's not really the same as classes) in Java are supposed to begin with a capital letter and not methods :) And moreover fields (like Length in this case) are not supposed to be public either :) But otherwise, it's really similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching to do that:

```
    String s ="http://www.example.org/ab/app/ram/ri/000000000000004";

   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/(\\d+)");
   Matcher m= p.matcher(s);
   if (m.find()){
       System.out.println(m.group(1));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string yourUrl = "Sample String"
```

string[] res1= yourUrl.Split('/');
string res2= res1[res1.Length - 1];